# How to view xml in design mode in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development. I installed android studio 1.2.2 on osx 10.10 successfully. I downloaded the [devunwired/accessory-samples](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples) repo and I am trying to view the activity_client.xml in design mode, but I am not able to do so.

I think I am supposed to see the "Design" tab in the botton somewhere, but I do not see it. Here [is what I see](http://bit.ly/1C3QXo4). What do I need to do to see this .xml file in the graphical view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project isn't imported as Android module.
Also the folder "BluetoothGattPeripheral" must be the root of the module.

Either try to reopen the correct folder or use File -> New -> Project From existing sources and make sure you import it as Android Project/Module.

When you've done it correctly the "src/main/java" folder should be automatically chosen as "Source Root" and should turn blue.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to say one word:

[image]

Comment: I guess you didn't look at his screenshot?